# How to I fix Windows 7 boot issue after update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-update, windows-error-reporting

I forcibly shut down the computer while installing Windows 7 updates. After that, the computer starts up in almost half an hour. It works incredibly late. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe windows is rolling back the changes. Subsequent boots may become faster

Comment: After half an hour when it finally boots, did you try to check if there's any restore point and attempting system restore to an earlier date or state?